# how to get opposite results from a query Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How to get the opposite results from a **SELECT** query

Below is my query

```
  $fod = FodMap::select('*')
        ->where('fructose_level', $fructose == 1 ? '=' : '>=', $fructose)
        ->where('lactose_level', $lactose == 1 ? '=' : '>=', $lactose)
        ->where('polyols_level', $polyols == 1 ? '=' : '>=', $polyols)
        ->where('fructan_level', $fructan == 1 ? '=' : '>=', $fructan)
        ->get();
```

I want to get everything that doesn't fall under the above query. pls advice

Comment: Well, the opposite of `==` is `!=`, the opposite of `>=` is `<=`. Otherwise the question is not clear

Comment: Yes but in case it's used `!=` it will always be `>=` ;)

Comment: @DamienPirsy : above results gives the list of foods which user can't eat.. what i want it to get the results which not matching above,, is there anyoption
in laravel where i cant put "Wherere Not in' kind of statement on top of those Where clauses

Answer (score 0):

For making negative statement in Laravel use `whereNotIn` expression.

[laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/04-21-2014-mysql-query-where-field-is-not-equal-to-some-of-the-given-values?page=1)

Comment: Are you sure this will work? OP wants opposite results to whole query.

Comment: Based on his comment, it should do exactly what's needed.

Comment: Can you post the exact query please, so OP could try it? It's really interesting if it works or not.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Let's see what the questioner is going to say. Please take a look at the provided link. Unlike you (based on your profile info) I'm not Laravel expert. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought about your question for some time and I think the solution is not as complicated as you asked first (when I've read it first, I thought you want inverted result).

1. In one of your comments you wrote:

> above results gives the list of foods which user can't eat.. what i
>   want it to get the results which not matching above

2. I've read about fructose levels etc. In a nutshell, levels higher than 1 are bad, less than 1 are good.

So, solution is way too simple then:

```
$fod = FodMap::select('*')
        ->where('fructose_level', '<', $fructose)
        ->where('lactose_level', '<', $lactose)
        ->where('polyols_level', '<', $polyols)
        ->where('fructan_level', '<', $fructan)
        ->get();
```

Also, ternary operators in your original query do not make sense, because clause like:

```
->where('fructose_level', $fructose == 1 ? '=' : '>=', $fructose)
```

will always work as:

```
->where('fructose_level', '>=', $fructose)
```

Think about it.