# Laravel MySQL with where conditions avoid columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to perform following search query, when user sends values I want to get matching results

If any results contain "none" i want to remove it from where condition and check only matching values for others

**Example 1**

```
$fructose = high 
$lactose = mid 
$polyols = none 
$fructan = none
```

if so i want to check only matching results for $fructose=high and $lactose=mid

**Example 2**

```
$fructose = high 
$lactose = mid 
$polyols = mid 
$fructan = mid
```

If so I want to check all  matching results

Please advise, below is my current query

```
 $fod = FodMap::select('*')
        ->where('fructose_level', '>=', $fructose)
        ->where('lactose_level','>=', $lactose)
        ->where('polyols_level',  '>=', $polyols)
        ->where('fructan_level', '>=', $fructan)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Simply add a check. BTW why `>=` when the values are string? Only `=` would work.

Comment: @rr rr, you still didn't check best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054760/how-to-get-opposite-results-from-a-query-laravel  - but, you're using code from my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried to solve your problem by writing query using eloquent structure. You should manage value and operator in where condition as per your need.

You can write your query with if condition like this:

```
    $query = FodMap::select('*');
    if($fructose != none){
      $query = $query->where('fructose_level',$fructose);
    }
    if($lactose != none){
      $query = $query->where('lactose_level',$fructose);
    }
    if($polyols != none){
      $query = $query->where('polyols_level',$fructose);
    }
    if($fructan != none){
      $query = $query->where('fructan_level',$fructose);
    }

    $fod = $query->get();
```